# How to replace a string use regular expression in maven?

Tags: xml, maven

I tried to replace a string in a file when build from maven.

I did this:

```
<replace file="..." token="AssemblyVersion(&#34;${[0-9.]+}&#34;)" 
     value="AssemblyVersion(&#34;${major}.${build}.${scmRevision}&#34;)"/>
```

The maven program just doesn't work on regular expression.

Comment: Can you described where you like to do such things or what you like to achieve?

Comment: Just want to update a string of a file when compile the maven file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/), seems to be doing exactly what you need. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2335470/1990089) can be helpful as well.